# Validation in magento2 create account page

Tags: database, validation, magento2, account

How to remove validation for `"First Name" is a required value` by programmatically in magento2. I tried with name.phtml for remove mandatory field and that's working fine and tried with change db value also that work also fine. But I need to enable and disable `"First Name" is a required value`  from the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Remove validation from Login page: Copy login.phtml from below path:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml

to your theme location:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

and remove the below code from the form: data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'

Also, remove the data-validate from every field of that form.

Now you can add your custom validation according to your requirement.

Remove validation from Registration page: Copy register.phtml from below path:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

to your theme location:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

and remove the below code from the form: data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'

Also, remove the data-validate from every field of that form.

Now you can add your custom validation according to your requirement.